# Python: detect if just one of the given words appear in text file

Tags: python, networking, scripting, instance, netmiko

I am trying to get my program to see if one of the 3 words in "words" appears in the fine kal.txt, just the fact that one of the words appear us enough, but I can't seem to get it working.

My Code:

```
    textring = open('kal.txt', 'r')

    words  =['flapping', 'Unexpected', 'down']
    len_words = len(words)
    print(len_words)

    counter = 0

    while counter < len_words:
        if words[counter] in textring: 
            print('success')
            SAVE_FILE = open('warnings/SW_WARNING.txt', 'w+')
            SAVE_FILE.write(textring)

        counter += 1
```

This is the output I get in cmd:

```
    3
```

That is of course because it's printing the len_words which is 3.

Any suggestions why, or does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we read the file content. Then we loop over each word and check if it is in the text. If it is we write our info and leave the loop.

```
with open('kal.txt', 'r') as infile:
    text = infile.read()

words = ['flapping', 'Unexpected', 'down']
for word in words:
    if word in text:
        print('success')
        with open('warnings/SW_WARNING.txt', 'w+') as save_file:
            save_file.write(text)
        break
```

Please note the use of the `with` context manager. When you use `with` with `open` there's no need to close the file after the work is done - a task that you forgot to do in your program.

Additional note: A list is iterable. There's no need to use a counter and access the elements with their index. Working with an index is slower, harder to read and so it is considered "unpythonic". Just loop over the values themselves.

Comment: Thanks so much!
I was wondering whether I should include the "break" in my old code, but this makes sense. Thanks a lot for taking time to help, really appreciate it :)

Comment: The problem I face next is that the """with open('kal.txt', 'r') as infile:
    text = infile.read()""" is for file only
Instead of the file I need python to read the direct output from a switch, which is not a file, how can I do this?

Comment: So you mean getting input from network traffic? You might need the [`socket`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) module for that. I experimented with `socket` over 10 years ago. You might want to ask a new question concerning this.

Comment: Ok.
I already have the output from the switch, which is the log. But the code will have to look for bad words in this log.
I will create a new post :)